# Comment Overflow

Tags: bug, status-declined, layout

I just checked one of my question and I saw that the comments are overlapping with top network posts in the right panel.

[image]

Cannot reproduce on other SE sites.

Browser : Chrome canary for android

Comment: Happens only on travel?

Comment: Yes. Tried in SO, android, MSE and some beta sites

Comment: Canary builds are not supported. And mobile browsers on desktop - doubly so.

Comment: @Oded is there much different CE between canary and chrome?

Comment: At times - the Canary build can certainly have regressions in all sorts of parts. You can think of it as alpha/beta software.